# Error: "Encountered undefined provider! Usually this means you have a circular dependencies"

Tags: angular, typescript

Here's a somewhat useless error I'm getting in my Angular / TypeScript application. Until someone makes the error message better, what can we do about this? What are the most likely situations that cause this to happen?

```
Uncaught Error: Encountered undefined provider! Usually this means you have a circular dependencies (might be caused by using 'barrel' index.ts files.
    at Object.syntaxError 
    at eval     at Array.forEach (native) [<root>]
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata 
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata 
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary 
    at eval 
...
```

Comment: I wish the error would mention the provider in question! In a non-trivial app, there are a lot of providers to narrow down.

Comment: I don't think it could provide the exact name, since the very problem it's complaining about is it's just getting `undefined` somewhere in its providers, e.g.: [Foo1, Foo2, undefined, Foo3]. But it could give the index of the entry that's undefined or line number or something. I agree.

Answer (score 75):

It is very hard to tell from the error message which provider causes this issue. The way I managed to debug this is the following:

- I went into the ***node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js*** file
- I found the line where it says: "Encountered undefined provider! Usually this means you have a circular dependencies. This might be caused by using 'barrel' index.ts files."
- One line before I added `console.log('type', type);` in order to see in which file is the undefined provider (You can also console log other relevant variables there).
- In the relevant file I found the 'barrel' import that caused the issue, and replaced it with exact file path import.

Comment: while "cave man like" (surely the tool could output *something* if we ourselves can make this simple edit to get some context), this suggestion does at least let us get some info re the culprit.

Comment: I added a console.log(`looking for ${provider}, ${debugInfo}`);   The provider might be undefined, but the debugInfo gives on the context of the failure.

Comment: I had this error, and it turned out it was a problem with a barrel file. Once I stopped importing the barrel file and using it's exports and started to import those things directly, it worked. Took me two days though. 

Upgrading from 5 => 6 is quite a bit of work.

Comment: I used the above code from Neil `console.log(\`looking for ${provider}, ${debugInfo}\`);` and added the --verbose flag to my `ng build --prod` command and found it fairly helpful.

Comment: Thank you, you just saved me from a 5 hours straight. My problem was a dot in the import line.

Comment: In my case, there was no circular reference. I took care of several warnings and then all was well.

Comment: Instead of manipulating the angular bundle files, one may also put a breakpoint in the corresponding line in `compiler.js` file that includes the error message using browser dev tools. Once the breakpoint is hit, I investigated the call stack and found the `providers` array, which based on the types of the other imports helped me to trace down the faulty provider.

Comment: I encountered the same error in NativeScript Angular. Regardless how I'm changing `compiler.umd.js`, nothing happens. I have no idea where the error message is coming from. It's neither in the project `node_modules` directory, nor in the global npm `node_modules`.

Comment: thank you. i was able to fix following this answer.

Comment: Great solution but @Andrew-Spoda got a better solution to console log on the same line.
`console.error('\ntype: ', type, '\nproviders: ', (providers || []).map(p => p && (p.name || p.useClass || p.useValue || p.useFactory || p.useExisting)));`

It displays the indicates the actual undefined provider

Comment: i just came back to this answer after i don't know how long. still the most useful! thanks!

Answer (score 24):

For me, I just restart the `ng serve`

Comment: This makes sense especially after adding some new services / doing some renames  which might get stuck the process in some "module.... has no exported member...". Thanks.

Comment: Switch it off, then on again. Makes for the best fixing technique ever. :)

Comment: You are a genius! :)

Answer (score 22):

One possibility is trying to declare a service and module in the same file, and declaring the module before the service:

```
import {Injectable, NgModule} from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({providers: [FooService]}) // WRONG: used before declared
export class FooModule {
}

@Injectable()
export class FooService {
}
```

You can fix this by declaring the service first, or you can use [`forwardRef`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/forwardRef-function.html) like this:

```
import {forwardRef, Injectable, NgModule} from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({providers: [forwardRef(() => FooService)]})
export class FooModule {
}

@Injectable()
export class FooService {
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Is there a scenario where creating a forwardRef like this would be a bad idea?

Comment: I don't think forwardRef is ever dangerous, just unnecessary if your symbols are declared before theyre used. Sometimes it's better to put things in separate files though, but small/trivial module declarations aren't always worth the extra file.

Comment: I have my components in separate files. Would it be enough to declare the provider module first, or does it have to be initialized on the page before the other module?

Comment: If you're using TypeScript, and you have a file that imports another file, I think the compiler will cause everything to be loaded in the correct order. Sorry I just saw your comment; if you got this error any my solution didn't fix it, please post another solution :)

Comment: Your solution works for me. I was just wondering if the provider module had to be initialized before use, though it seems that simply declaring it is enough to get it working, as you have shown in your answer

Comment: Order of declaration really matters!

Comment: Didn't work for me the forwardRef thing. I don't want however, to put module and all my services in the same file!!!!

Answer (score 7):

I have no reputation yet to comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51304428/2549593
But better add following:

```
console.error('\ntype: ', type, '\nproviders: ', (providers || []).map(p => p && (p.name || p.useClass || p.useValue || p.useFactory || p.useExisting)));
```

It will display providers list and module with the problem, so you can open it, and check this providers list: one which was marked as undefined - should be fixed

Comment: Thanks for this - enabled me to find my stupid error that had been holding me up for a day.

Answer (score 5):

I was running into this while using ng-packagr to package a library then importing it into another library.  What ended up being my problem was indeed the 'barrel' index.ts imports.

This was making it break

```
import { Activate, Another, Data } from './services
@NgModule({ providers: [ Activate, Another, Data ]})
```

where in the services folder I had one index.ts file that was exporting all of the services.

This fixed it:

```
import { Activate } from './services/activate.service.ts'
import { Another} from './services/another.service.ts'
import { Data } from './services/data.service.ts'
@NgModule({ providers: [ Activate, Another, Data ]})
```

Answer (score 2):

Got this error running --prod.

You can't import things like that:

```
import { MyService } from '.';
```

You should use the full path

```
import { MyService } from './my.service'
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometime this issue occurred because of some dependency in third party api used in angular app. I faced same issue and resolved it using following steps:

1. Removed package.lock.json file
2. Deleted node_modules folder
3. Again run npm install
4. Run "ng build --prod"
   These steps will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the module can find the service you have mentioned.

In my case I was exporting a `guard` from my `guards` folder. this folder contained an index.ts file. There were two more files in this `guards` folder `auth.guard.ts` and `company.guard.ts`. 
Ideally I **should have exported** these files in the index as follows:

contents of **guards/index.ts**

```
export * from './auth.guard';
export * from './company.guard'; // forgot this
```

But I forgot to include the line above that exports from `company.guard.ts`. This was creating problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also console logged the value ***right before the error message*** statement in *node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js* file.

And checked that ***Document interface*** was there in **providers array** of a **component** which was the root cause.

I **removed it to fix** this issue.

Answer (score 1):

in my case i changes this

```
  @Injectable()
    export class LocationTracker {
    }
```

to

```
  @Injectable()
    export class LocationTrackerProvider {
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case I just deleted the @Injectable() decorator from my service(cause it didn't need any services to be injected in it)

Answer (score 1):

In case of Ionic

```
@NgModule({
providers: [ storage, ... ]
})
```

remove storage from app.module.ts
since @ionic/storage 2.x.x
we import IonicStorageModule instead of storage

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when missing an import for an override of an angular class. I imagine an incorrect import may cause the error in other ways also.

In my case I had no import statement for `File` and it defaulted to a File interface which wasn't what I wanted. Adding `import { File } from "@ionic-native/file"` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-dispatching-history",
  templateUrl: "./dispatching-history.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./dispatching-history.component.css"],
  providers: [RecommendationService, Location, { provide: HashLocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }]
})
```

I just added `Location, { provide: HashLocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }` as a provider in one of my component and didn't do any other necessary changes in files like app.module.ts. I don't need it anymore, so I simply remove it. And the command `ng build -c deploy --build-optimizer --aot --prod --sourceMap` works again.

Answer (score 0):

I got my way around this by flattening all of the barrel imports(which kinda defeats the purpose of using barrel files in the first place, but I can't afford losing more time on this).

Answer (score 0):

in my case, very simple, it was really *undefined provider* in the module definition.
Because the lib I used, had an option to **dynamically** change their providers and it was wrong configured, so it loaded `undefined` as providers.

Answer (score 0):

My the `Angular project` when use npm `angular library` packaging raise error:

```
ERROR in : Encountered undefined provider! Usually this means you have a circular dependencies. This might be caused by using 'barrel' index.ts files.
```

This is because define alias on `public_api.ts`

example :

```
// it's wrong
export { HeaderService as HeaderService } from "./lib/services/header.service";
// this is correct
export { HeaderService } from "./lib/services/header.service";
```