# ionic error : help to resolve it

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

**I have service**

```
 import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
 import {Http} from '@angular/http';
 import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class MainService{
http:any;
baseUrl:String;

constructor (http:Http){
    this.http = http;
    this.baseUrl = 'https://someurl.ru/api/';
}

getCategories(){
    return this.http.get(this.someurl+ 'catalog.getTopCategories').map(res => {
        return res.json();
    })
 }}
```

**and i declared it in my app.component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import {MainService} from './services/main.service';

 import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

 @Component({
 templateUrl: 'app.html',
 providers: [MainService]
 })
 export class MyApp {
     rootPage:any = TabsPage;

     constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: 
     SplashScreen) {
      platform.ready().then(() => {
     statusBar.styleDefault();
   splashScreen.hide();
   });
 }
}
```

then i start project it gives me an error:

**Uncaught Error: Encountered undefined provider! Usually this means you have a circular dependencies (might be caused by using 'barrel' index.ts files.**

**How can i resolve it?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: "Encountered undefined provider! Usually this means you have a circular dependencies"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008395/error-encountered-undefined-provider-usually-this-means-you-have-a-circular-d)

Comment: @RameshRajendran forwardRef method did not help me, have you another solutions?

Comment: set as provider in the module not in the component

Comment: declare same inside provider in app.module.ts file.