# ERROR in : Encountered undefined provider! Usually this means you have a circular dependencies (might be caused by using 'barrel' index.ts files

Tags: angular, webpack

I extensively use the barrel notion on my Angular 5 application. As an example, in the **core** Module, I have a **services** folder that export each of the app's models like this (in the *index.ts* file):

```
import { ApiService } from '@core/services/api.service';

export const services: Array<any> = [
    ApiService
];

export * from '@core/services/api.service';
```

Then, I spread these models in the providers key in the core.module :

```
import * as fromServices from '@core/services';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  providers: [...fromServices.services],
  exports: []
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

When I compile the app with yarn start, everything works fine. But when I do

**ng build --prod**

I'm getting the following error :

> ERROR in : Encountered undefined provider! Usually this means you have
>   a circular dependency (might be caused by using 'barrel' index.ts
>   files.

My imports are named like this in the **tsconfig.json file** :

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
  "paths": {
    "@core/*": ["app/core/*"],
  }
 }
}
```

Any help/tips would be much appreciated.

> **Update/Workaround #1:**
>   Turning off the AOT by issuing the following command makes the build
>   pass but without AOT : **ng build -prod -aot=false**

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by removing all the providers from the app module and inserting them back one by one then running the
```ng build --prod``` after each insert.

Comment: Or you could find the specific provider which causes the error. I followed this answer , and it helped me out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51304428/1305026