# Ionic 3 “Encountered undefined provider! Usually this means you have a circular dependencies” might be caused by using 'barrel' index.ts files

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

Here's a somewhat useless error I'm getting in my Angular/TypeScript application. Until someone makes the error message better, what can we do about this? What are the most likely situations that cause this to happen? Here my app.module.js file and home.ts files there.

When I remove file and file opener plugin it's not getting an error. If I include that plugin in home.ts it shows the error. What are the most likely situations that cause this to happen?

app.module.ts:

```ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import {  FileOriginal } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { FileOpenerOriginal } from '@ionic-native/file-opener';
        @NgModule({
          declarations: [
            MyApp,
            HomePage
          ],
          imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
          ],
          bootstrap: [IonicApp],
          entryComponents: [
            MyApp,
            HomePage
          ],
          providers: [
            StatusBar,
            SplashScreen,
            {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
            FileOriginal,
            FileOpenerOriginal
          ]
        })
        export class AppModule {}
```

home.ts

```ts
import {  FileOriginal } from '@ionic-native/file';
import {  FileOpenerOriginal } from '@ionic-native/file-opener'

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private plt: Platform, private file: FileOriginal, private fileOpener: FileOpenerOriginal) {
          }
```

I got an error like this:

```
Uncaught Error: Encountered undefined provider! 
Usually this means you have a circular dependencies (might be caused by using 'barrel' index.ts files.)
      at syntaxError (compiler.js:486)  
      at compiler.js:15767  
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)  
      at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (compiler.js:15752)  
      at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15320)  
      at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:34413)  
      at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34374)
```

Comment: have you tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008395/error-encountered-undefined-provider-usually-this-means-you-have-a-circular-d

Comment: thanks bro, my error occur in file and file opener plugin... in this solution error occur in module

Comment: What is `FileOriginal` ? https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/file/

Comment: i install this plugin `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file` . i declare in provider name as file. it show error and recommand to add fileOriginal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need  to use File not FileOriginal. In my project i declare File as a provider and it work . Do you install it correctly ?
 When you  use  this command  `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file` , did you have any dependencies warning ?
 Maybe the version of the plugin is not compatible with the ionic 3.

**EDIT**

Command :

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
npm install @ionic-native/file@4.2.0
```

Comment: when i use file`                                                                                                                                       (alias) class FileOpenerOriginal
import FileOpenerOriginal
@name — File Opener

@description — This plugin will open a file on your device file system with its default application.

@usage

 * import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener/ngx';
 *
 * constructor(private fileOpener: FileOpener) { }
 *
 * ...`

Comment: Like I said , did you install it properly ? You use the 2 command ? In my package.json  I have this for ionic 3 : `"@ionic-native/file": "^4.20.0"` and this : ` "cordova-plugin-file": "6.0.1",`

Comment: i added  `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="6.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-opener2" spec="2.2.0">`

Comment: But can you tell me  what version you have in your package json ?

Comment: `> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file@4.2.0 --save
Installing "cordova-plugin-file" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-compat" for android
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 7.1.4, failed version requirement:
      <6.3.0
Skipping 'cordova-plugin-compat' for android`

Comment: I think you need to uninstall  plugin-compat ,  cordova-plugin-compat is now included in cordova-android 6.3.0, no need add plugin again.  I edit my answer try to do the command I give you ^^, and don't forget to add remove platform sometimes its just a bug.